# Trying to get WSL working on a Windows Server 2019 VM. Getting 'Access denied' error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I am trying to enable WSL with Ubuntu on a VM with Windows Server 2019. I am using the Powershell, running as Admin and following instructions here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server .

After enabling WSL, I restarted and run :

`Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`

I can status shows as enabled. When I run wsl command I get a access denied message:

```
PS C:\> wsl
Access is denied.
```

I went ahead and downloaded Ubuntu distro and ran the executable:

```
PS C:\Users\ad_svoorakk\Ubuntu> ./ubuntu1804.exe
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
Access is denied.
Please create a default UNIX user account. The username does not need to match your Windows username.
For more information visit: https://aka.ms/wslusers
Enter new UNIX username:
```

When I enter a username, I see an access denied message and am prompted for username again.

```
Enter new UNIX username: xxxxxxx
Access is denied.
Enter new UNIX username:
```

Is there something happening here because this is a VM and there is something I need to do differently? Or does WSL run on VMs at all?

Comment: Yes, WSL 1 works in VMs. With WSL 2, things are a little more complicated but it is not yet generally released.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Please read the question again. OP is asking whether WSL can run in a VM. It can, because WSL 1 does not use a VM.

Comment: Fair enough, but VMs can run nested. It's been years since this became available.

Comment: Yes they can, but not universally. Hyper-V in particular is very picky about this. Depending on the exact software setup it may or may not work.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a specific setting that I need to check?

Comment: No, your problem isn’t about running in a VM. Googling “wsl access denied” yields some results, bot no solutions. Well, one: apparently communication with the LxssManager service can somehow fail or the service itself or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue.  For my particular issue, the root cause was traced to McAfee End Point Security.  McAfee End Point has a McAfee-defined Access Protection rule that blocks WSL execution.  Once this rule was disabled, WSL and Ubuntu started working without issue.